# Get button click on UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a simple table view which looks like this 
[image]

Each button overflows some part to next cell (part of requirement).

I want that **overflowing button's click event**. How to get that ?

By default its taking it as cell click rather than button click if i click on that overflowing part.

I have created a [dummy code](https://github.com/aishwat/test) which changes button color on click, so it is easy for someone to try it out. same layout.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Below is the original image , what i am trying to do , for simplicity sake i scaled it down to a button 
**Lets assume req is u cant change height and cant play around table view separator**

[image]

Comment: Does clicking just the table view cell perform a segue?

Comment: Set Tag for Each cell's Button. And then in Button Action check for tag and perform the action respectively.

Comment: @rigdonmr no segue , Balaji but it wont go to Button Check , checking tag comes later

Comment: hasya, arturdev , actual requirement is somewhat like this , edited post , i scaled down it to a button

Comment: You have to make clear your question earlier.  
Well, That is another tableview you need to make animate like scroll down which you could do it easily. best luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement 'tableView:heightForRowAtIndexpath:` method and return greater value than it has now. Your cells don't have enough height to display buttons fully, and because of that some part of your button hides behind of next cell. You can be convinced easily by checking "Clip subviews" checkbox of your Cell Prototype in the interface builder, and if you will see that buttons will be clipped.

---

EDIT

Check this: https://github.com/arturdev/test

[image]

Comment: i know , but overflow is a part of requirement , its mentioned, and its coming on next cell , bcoz clip is false

Comment: Than you can do following. Hide tableView separator by setting "Separator" to "None" from storyboard for your tableView. Then, make cell's height bigger, so the buttons could displayed completely, then add your custom separator at the same Y position that you have now. For custom separator you can add a UIView with 1pt height and set background color to lightGrayColor.

Comment: actual requirement is a container view over there , which has one more table view , basically a spinner kinda , but i simplified problem statement and made it as button, so this approach is not doable

Comment: Then if you can post here a screenshot of actual requirement, we can tell you how to do that..  
I'm pretty sure, that `hitTest:withEvent` solution is too much for this job and you can have more simple and beautiful solution.

Comment: @aishwatsingh See edited answer. I think this is more beautiful, simple and clean solution ;)

Comment: @aturdev whooa, its great. Exactly what i was looking for. Other solution was to use pop over but it had issue while scrolling. simple `addsubview` :D thanks limbo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `UITableView` and override `hitTest:withEvent:` and figure out if `point` is within the frame of one of the buttons. Return the button if the point is within the frame or just return `[super hitTest:point withEvent:event]` otherwise.

You can use `CGRectContainsPoint` and `[UIView convertRect/Point:to/fromView:]` to make calculation easier.

`hitTest:withEvent:` is a way for the system to ask the outermost view who will receive the event at a given location.

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: i am still not able to get hitTest , possible for u to make a commit in git ? i know its a lot to ask, or can i use `touchesBegan:withEvent:`

Comment: @aishwatsingh I've opened the pr https://github.com/aishwat/test/pull/1 check it out

Comment: Thanks , this works in current scenario, vl try it in actual case. Still looking for some cleaner approach , if i dont find anything better by tomorrow , vl accept this as answer

Comment: BTW I know that this is not up to you, but I think a better design approach is to use UIPicker and present it as a popover on iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Make UITableView seperator to None. draw 1 or 2 pixel height label with black background color in cell.

Make cell selection style none in cellForRowAtIndex.

```
cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Manage proper autolayout or autoresizing mask.

Just tried with your code.

Download from [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKSXlYd3dLZDMycFU/view?usp=sharing)

Image

[image]